# Why do Roth IRAs have income limits if you can just do a backdoor IRA contribution?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, roth-conversion

As we all know, Roth IRAs have income limits that prohibit individuals from contributing to a Roth IRA if their Modified Adjusted Gross Income is over a certain limit ($133,000 for individual contributors, and $196,000 for a married couple filing jointly in 2017).

It is my understanding that one way around this restriction is to use a [Backdoor Roth IRA](http://www.rothira.com/what-is-a-backdoor-roth-ira), where a traditional IRA can be converted into a Roth IRA. Any pre-tax income that has been placed into a traditional IRA is taxed when it is converted into a Roth IRA, and any post-tax income is not.

My question is: doesn't this allow people to get around the MAGI income limit restriction on a Roth IRA? If someone can just convert their Traditional IRA to a Roth IRA with no penalty (other than the tax they would have had to pay to contribute to the Roth IRA in the first place which isn't really a penalty), doesn't it mean that the limits on Roth IRAs are basically irrelevant or easily avoided?

Comment: It wasn't _intended_ that way, that's why it's called _backdoor conversion_

Comment: Note that not everyone can take advantage of backdoor Roth IRA contributions. If one has existing pre-tax money in Traditional IRA or other pre-tax IRAs, the pro-rata rule means that any conversion to Roth IRA will have to convert both pre-tax money and post-tax money, leading to taxes on the conversion of pre-tax money, and leaving some post-tax money behind in the pre-tax IRA (unless all the money is converted), which makes it no longer the same as a direct Roth IRA contribution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There used to be income limits on Roth conversions. They were eliminated in 2010 by the [Tax Increase Prevention and Reconciliation Act of 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_Increase_Prevention_and_Reconciliation_Act_of_2005#Conversions_to_Roth_IRAs), probably to increase tax revenue. This combined with the lack of income limits on non-deductible Traditional IRAs opened up the backdoor Roth IRA. We don't know if politicians intended this, but closing it now would be disadvantageous to upper-middle class taxpayers, and as such is not straightforward to accomplish politically. It's obviously not an ideal situation for those who would like a clear yes or no as to whether they can make a Roth IRA contribution, but it's a consequence of the current state of U.S. politics.